# LINQ Concat to stack?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently taking a list of files with a linq query:

```
result = GetFiles(set.localPath)
         .OrderByDescending(info => info.CreationTime)
         .Take(set.latestImageStacksize)
         .Select(file => file.FullName)
         .ToList();
```

I'm trying to stack this list to an already existing stack. I tried using linq but I didnt get the result I wanted, so I resorted to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < set.latestImageStacksize; i++)
{
   FilesToDisplay.Push(result[i]);
}
```

Is there a better way to merge the resulting list above with the stack?

Comment: `foreach` seems better than `for` when you do not need the index in your logic. By the way, you cannot use `result[i]` (indexer access) if `result` is declared as an `IEnumerable<>` (and the return type of `Select` is that).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen it is worth to note I'm avoiding the use of `foreach` loops because of the extra garbage they generate. I did not want to actually create a new stack each time that would result in even more of that...

Comment: To me it sounds like a wrong idea to avoid `foreach`. Rest assured that `foreach` will be designed in a good way. What garbage are you referring to? You mean the enumerator object returned by `GetEnumerator()`? In some cases, that is a public (often nested) `struct`, and then the enumerator is just on the stack like your `for` iteration variable `i`. Also, to even use `for` in the example from your question above, you have to do `.ToList()`, or similar, first (not shown in your question), and that wastes resources and generates garbage in itself.

Comment: foreach here seems indeed as the lesser evil ! thanks @JeppeStigNielsen

Answer (score 1):

If result is of type `IEnumerable` then you can do this:

```
result.ToList().ForEach(FilesToDisplay.Push);
```

If it is already a `List` then obviously you don't have to use `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this fairly frequently, it could be worth writing an extension method for `Stack` like so:

```
public static class StackExt
{
    public static void PushRange<T>(this Stack<T> stack, IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        // Null checks elided for simplicity.

        foreach (var item in range)
            stack.Push(item);
    }
}
```

Then you would just do:

```
FilesToDisplay.PushRange(result);
```

However, if you are not going to do that often you should just use the hard-coded loop that you're already using. Extension methods should be used lightly.

Note that if you were creating a NEW stack rather than pushing onto an existing one, you could create the new stack like so:

```
var FilesToDisplay = new Stack<string>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not. You can hide that "ugly" loop behind another function or even extension method to make it look pretty on the outside, but the functionality remains the same.